# Javascript loop with sqlite code

Tags: javascript, sqlite, loops

I use the below code

```
        t.executeSql('SELECT buildingcode, flatname, flatdescription FROM buildingflats WHERE buildingcode = ? ORDER BY flatname ASC',[buildingcode], function(t, resultflatcomment) {
            var j,
                lenflatcomments = resultflatcomment.rows.length,
                rowflatcomments,
                row;

            if (lenflatcomments > 0 ) {
                for (j = 0; j < lenflatcomments; j += 1) {
                    rowflatcomments = resultflatcomment.rows.item(j);
                    alert(rowflatcomments.flatname);
                    t.executeSql('SELECT DISTINCT flatdescription, flatname, buildingcode FROM bill WHERE buildingcode = ? AND flatdescription = ?',[buildingcode, rowflatcomments.flatname], function(t, resultflat) {
                        var len = resultflat.rows.length;

                        if (len > 0) {
                            row = resultflat.rows.item(0);
                            alert(row.flatdescription);

                        } else {
                            alert(rowflatcomments.flatname);

                        }
                        $("#opt2").selectmenu('refresh');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

but the `alert(rowflatcomments.flatname);` is executed before SQLite selection inside the loop.

The rowflatcomments.flatname is always the last selection of buildingflats.

How can I fix it??

Comment: I don't know exactly, just a question. where is semi colon on your sql?

Comment: the alert in nullDataHandler. Simply I guess the query is not suitable. inevitably nullDatahandler function called when your executeSql called.

Comment: the SQL select will be sent off and the loop will continue to execute. The callback of the SQL select will execute whenever its finished. Does that answer you question?

Furthermore its possible for you to get `lenflatcomments` number of alerts and THEN have all the callbacks executed. It is also posible for the callbacks to not be in the same order that they were sent off. The only thing that is guaranteed is that the alerts will happen in order one after another.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand

Comment: Ok how can i fix this? Sorry but my English are terible.

Comment: Because the sql select is asynchronous, the alert will be called repeatedly for the number of rows. Then when each select is finished executing the callback will be called. To fix it, put the alert inside of the callback.

Comment: which alert? How to use callbacks?

Comment: Can someone help me with the code?